# Why deviceToken is passed in NSData type, in application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

Why the received `deviceToken` in `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is a NSData?

Aren't we always converting it to `NSString`/`String` and send it to our backend? Is there any other use case that made Apple to use `NSData` type(instead of `NSString`/`String`) for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:), it reads

> The APNs servers require a binary format for performance reasons.

So I assume their intention was to avoid the two conversions in the cycles: NSData to NSString, send to server, server convert to binary format, send to APNs.

Or since they're expecting it in binary format, they might as well give it to you in binary format.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.